# Node JS Passport - 400 Bad request for register

Tags: node.js, postgresql, passport.js

I try to implement a register on my web app, using Node JS and Passport.js for local authentication, but I have this error when I Post the request on Insomnia (Like Postman) :

```
Bad Request
```

I don't understand because I have follow a tutorial that I find on Google to do this.
Here is the route (auth.js):

```
const passport = require('passport');
const router = require('express').Router();
//const UserController = require('../controller/UserController');

router
    // login
    .post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", function(req, res, next) {
        console.log(req);
    }))
    // logout
    .get('/logout', (req, res, next) => {
        req.session.destroy((err) => {
            res.redirect('/login')
        })
    })
    // signup
    .post("/signup", passport.authenticate("local-register"), (req, res) => {
        var userInfo = req.body;
    })

module.exports = router;
```

Here is Passport.js file :

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
const db = require("./queries");
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(authenticate))
passport.use("local-register", new LocalStrategy({passReqToCallback: false}, register))

function authenticate(email, password, done) {
    db.one('select * from users where email = $1', email)
        .then((user) => {
            if(!user || !bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {
                return done(null, false, {message: "invalid user and password combination"});
            }
            done(null, user)
        }, done);
}

function register(email, password, done) {
    db.one('select * from users where email = $1', email)
        .then((user) => {
            if(user) {
                return done(null, false, {message: "An user with this address have already been created."});
            }
            const newUser = {
                email: email,
                password: bcrypt.hashSync(password),

            };
            db.none('insert into users(email, password) values($1, $2)', [newUser.email, newUser.password])
                .then((ids) => {
                    newUser.id = ids[0]
                    done(null, newUser)
                })
        })
}

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    db.one('select * from users where id = $1', id)
        .then((user) => {
            done(null, user)
        }, done);
});
```

I'm using Postgresql as DB for this project, with pg-promise package.

And this is the app.js file :

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var session = require('express-session');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var passport = require('passport')
require('./passport');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var usersRoutes = require('./routes/users');
var authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

app.use('/', index);
app.use(usersRoutes);
app.use(authRoutes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Doest anyone know why I have this response ? I try with a post method using email and password on Insomnia,

Thank you !

Comment: What tutorial did you follow? At least as far as `pg-promise` goes, your code is invalid there: In two places there you are calling `db.one`, and then process the result as if it were from `db.oneOrNone`. You should check the [library's API](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html) for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, LocalStrategy expects to find credentials in parameters named username and password. ([passport-local on Github](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local#parameters)).

So you need to edit this line and set `usernameField` to `email`

```
passport.use("local-register", new LocalStrategy({passReqToCallback: false, usernameField: 'email'}, register))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your passport.js file on line 4, ensure you end your line `;`

`const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');`

You can authenticate your details individually as well

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy((email, password, done) => {
 User.getUserByEmail(email, (err, email) => {
  if(err) throw err;
  if(!email){
    return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect Username/Email'});
  }

  User.comparePassword(password, user.password, (err, isMatch)=>{
    if(err) return done(err);
    if(isMatch){
      return done(null, email);
    } else {
      return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid Password'});
    }
  });
})
}));
```

Try to stick to one way of writing your code, either ES6 or ES5. And when using ES6, I will advise you use `'use strict'` to help you thoroughly check your codes for error.